# probability: best linear predictor $\hat{Y} = aX + b$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $X\sim\mathcal{U}(-1, 1)$ and $Y = X^2$.

Since the best linear predictor is defined as
$$
\hat{Y} = E_Y[Y] + \frac{\text{cov}(X, Y)}{\text{var}(X)}(x - E_X[X]) 
$$
Can I simple just write it as
$$
\hat{Y} = E_Y[X^2] + \frac{\text{cov}(X, X^2)}{\text{var}(X)}(x - E_X[X]) 
$$
and since $E[X] = 0$, $E[X^2] = 1$, and $E[X^3] = 0$, we have that
\begin{align}
\hat{Y} &= 1 + (E[XY] - E[X]E[Y])(x - 1)\\
&= 1 + (E[X^3] - E[X]E[X^2])(x - 1)\\
&= 1 + (0 - 0\cdot 1)(x - 1)\\
&= 1
\end{align}
This just seems like a strange answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you get $E[X^2]=1$.
In fact, it is 1/3.

Other than that, you are correct: since $\text{cov}(X,X^2)=0$, the best linear predictor is a constant.

Comment: I integrated ($\int_0^1x^2dx)$) - but I thought that $X$ was continuous uniform on $[-1;1]$ and you seem to mean that it is discreet. At any rate, the conclusion stands - the best predictor is a constant, except that in your case $Y=X^2$ is actually a constant $1$.